# How to check current password when reset password in firebase and Expo?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm adding password reset function using react native expo and firebase api.

[image: UI link]

First input is current password.

Second input is new password.

And third input is confirm new password.

To check the current password, I have to get current password.

Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reauthenticateWithCredential()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#reauthenticatewithcredential) to verify user's password and then [`updatePassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#updatepassword) to update it:

```
import { getAuth, reauthenticateWithCredential, EmailAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();

const resetUserPassword = async () => {
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  const cred = EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, "[USER_PASSWORD]");

  try {
    await reauthenticateWithCredential(user, cred)
   
    // User entered correct credentials
    // Update password
    await updatePassword(auth.currentUser, "[NEW_PASSWORD]");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.code, e.message)
    // Could be incorrect credentials
  }
}
```

Updating password requires a recent login re-authentication is necessary if user is logged in for long time.